# Displaying Image in QTableview PyQT

Tags: pyqt5, qtreeview, qabstracttablemodel

I am trying to make a file browser imitation in PyQt5. Files to be displayed in one horizontal row (similar to adobe lightroom). Used Qtreeview with two rows, 1 for filename to be displayed another for a thumbnail and QAbstractTableModel. Managed to populate filename columns using this code:

```
def data(self,index,role):
    if not index.isValid():
        return None
    if index.row()==1 and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return (self.array[index.column()])

    if index.row()==1 and role ==QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
        return QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
```

tried different ways to populate thumbnails with no success. Could not find anything online to solve this. Most of tutorials and examples are for C.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I think you can manually draw the layout like a sketch, in order to understand what you want.